Marie-Sklodowska-Curie actions: publish a part of the proposal just after the deadline?
I am applying for the Marie-Sklodowska-Curie Actions Fellowship (MSCA) in physics this year. The proposal includes developing a novel theoretical method, applying it to various models, and making a framework that translates the parameters of these models to the impact on some observables.
The point is that I have developed a prototype of this method and am going to submit a paper to arXiv. My naive plan was to submit it right after the MCSA deadline. On the one hand, the prototype is a kind of proof of principle, i.e., it cannot be applied to most of the models from the box and just demonstrates that it is, in principle, possible to achieve the basic requirements outlined in the proposal. On the other hand, it implements some of the fundamental features I mentioned in the proposal and includes some simple case studies.
My question is whether this may severely affect the chance of my proposal being approved. Namely, when searching for papers similar to my proposal, referees will find my own paper, decide that some part of the project has already been done, and then reject the project.
I am wondering whether I should mention the forthcoming paper in the proposal, or just drop it completely. Also, how should I write the paper's abstract in order to avoid some issues if the paper is found.
What do you think?
Edit
Can the scenario of not mentioning this paper and then being discovered by the referees be positive? They will see that the prototype demonstrates the principal possibility of developing the method discussed in the proposal, which may reveal some risks.

My situation ditto. But, I am mentioning in my proposal about my pilot study and also providing my results in brief to give the reviewers a bit of confidence jn my research ideas.

@Coder : good idea, I will probably proceed in a similar fashion.


My question is whether this may severely affect the chance of my proposal being approved. Namely, when searching for papers similar to my proposal, referees will find my own paper, decide that some part of the project has already been done.

This seems like a plausible concern. If you are saying in the proposal "I am going to do X" and you have already done X at the time when the proposal is being evaluated, it would indeed be quite reasonable for the reviewer to not recommend your proposal for funding. If I were the reviewer I would ask myself why you are asking for money to do something that you've already done, and why I should recommend to the funding agency to give you that money.
However, much would depend on how you frame your description of your plans, and what else you say you will do aside from X. For example, let's imagine that instead of saying "I am going to do X", you write: "I am going to do X, and then proceed with follow-up work Y and Z. In fact, I am close to finishing a paper where I do X. This sets the ground for achieving the [much more important] goals Y and Z." Suddenly the fact that you are about to finish X appears to be a positive rather than a negative. It makes your proposal seem more suitable for funding: you are pursuing important goals Y and Z, and you are making yourself look like you are well positioned to pursue them -- better positioned in fact than someone who is just proposing to do Y and Z without X, or than someone who is proposing to do X, Y and Z and hasn't yet made any progress on any of those goals. (This is assuming that there is some relevant conceptual relationship between X, Y, Z, e.g., that X is some natural first step on the path towards Y and Z.)

I am wondering whether I should mention the forthcoming paper in the proposal, or just drop it completely.

See above. Again, things depend a lot on the details of what you are proposing so I can't give a definite answer. But I would say that a good research proposal will do a good job of communicating where you are at the moment with your work on the topic of the research, and where you plan to go from there. So if you are about to publish a paper, that could be a good thing to mention, as it shows you are already fairly advanced in your thinking on the topic and have a good foundation to build on for continued work; but this rule of thumb assumes the premise that the main thing you are proposing is that continued work (the "Y and Z" from my discussion above) rather than the things you will do in the forthcoming paper. If the paper is not the beginning of something bigger but rather the end of a research project, then it might be better to not mention it and focus the proposal on the other things you are planning to do.

Also, how should I write the paper's abstract in order to avoid some issues if the paper is found.

Just write the abstract as you would if you were not submitting a proposal. The existence of the proposal is simply irrelevant for writing the abstract -- most people reading the abstract will not even know about your proposal, let alone read it. However, the existence of the paper is not irrelevant for writing the proposal: you need to carefully think about the paper's relationship to the research you are proposing, and mention it (or possibly not mention it) in a way that optimizes the overall impression your proposal will make on the reviewers.
